# Vectorized power function in armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

The armadillo library has a function `pow(A, p)` to raise all elements of vector/matrix `A` to the power `p`.  Is there a function in armadillo, std, or elsewhere that performs element-wise  power?  That is, raises each element in vector `A` to the corresponding power in vector `p`?

Comment: @KerrekSB, that would use the same exponent for each element of c -- not what the OP asked

Comment: @rerx: Indeed, deleted. Thanks.

Comment: How about exp(p*log(A))?

Answer (score 2):

There is no predefined function of that kind in Armadillo.

Here is a quick self-made version, that however will not benefit from any delayed expression evaluation template features of Armadillo:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>

template<class Object>
Object elementwise_pow(const Object& base, const Object& p) {
    assert(base.n_elem == p.n_elem);
    Object result;
    result.copy_size(base);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < result.n_elem; ++i) {
        result[i] = std::pow(base[i], p[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    arma::mat m(3,3);
    m.fill(2.);
    arma::mat p(3,3);
    p << 1 << 2 << 3 << arma::endr
      << 4 << 5 << 6 << arma::endr
      << 7 << 8 << 9 << arma::endr;
    arma::mat r = elementwise_pow(m, p);
    r.print(std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

An optimizing compiler should also easily **vectorize** this code.